# OnItemClickListener that can have more or less items

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, onitemclicklistener

I have a server with a database. In my database I have 25 items at the moment but will be adding items and removing them.

I have the `ListView` in java working for the 25 items by simply writing a switch n case method.

But how could I write it so that as items in my data base are added or removed it adds the extra case items to my on `ItemListener`.

This is how I have it at the moment but I don't want to update my app every time I add a new item

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Edit**

this is how i add the items to the list using firebase

```
mrootref = new Firebase("my firebaselink");
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvnames);

mrootref.child("Mydatabase name").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
        final ArrayAdapter<String> jlistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, webstreamsArray);
        lv.setAdapter(jlistAdapter);

        String streamname = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        jlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        webstreamsArray.add(streamname);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

below ive included a screenshot of my database structure. my app then calls the name part of the database and populates them to my listview. if an item is deleted it removes the item from my listview. i want to use the "url" item so that when the name item is clicked it opens the url item

[image]

Comment: why are you  using switch case

Comment: what would you recomend @NJ

Comment: You can't dynamically add code at run time. All items in your Adapter are going to receive the exact same event. You do not need a switch on the position

Comment: dynamically add code?

Comment: ive added more to my code to see if this helps

Comment: What is the onClick action you'd like to do? Even if it is different for every item, surely there will be a way to identify which action to take without explicitly writing all actions in cases

Comment: it opens a different link dependent on Which name from my database is called ill add the database structure to my code now @howdoidothis

Comment: Well assuming you're keeping all these links in a data structure (an array, a map, etc), just make sure the index 'i' of the item clicked can be used to retreive it's corresponding link

Comment: added more to my question hope this helps

Comment: Just to clarify, why do you need switch-case if all child items can be handled in the same way? You have index `i` and you have your data, so just access the data and do something like `openUrl(urlList[i])`? (I'm making up the method name and list name here). As for item deletions, you probably need a separate listener, such as a long press listener. Therefore, whether you have 0 items, or 10 items, or 100 items, the code behaves the same way, which is to open the link based on the index.

Comment: brill thanks that worked ill share my answer Thanks guys and thanks @KevinLee for the full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what ive come up with from the help of you guys

```
 Urlname = snapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
            jlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            webstreamsArray.add(streamname);
            urlList.add(Urlname);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                   WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(urlList.get(i));

                }
            });
        }
```